# How to wrap c++ code that uses boost.asio using boost.python?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am trying to wrap some c++ code that uses boost.asio with boost.python.

When I build the library with bjam, it creates the .so files but then when I try to import it from my python script, I get the following error

ImportError: /path/to/timer_ext.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv

Here is my code :

timer.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
        #include <boost/asio.hpp>
        #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

        #include <boost/python/module.hpp>
        #include <boost/python/def.hpp>

      char const* test()
{
        boost::asio::io_service io; 
        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        t.wait();

        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

        return "Done.";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(timer_ext)
{
        using namespace boost::python;
        def("test", test);
}
```

Jamroot

```
import python ;

if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    ECHO "notice: no Python configured in user-config.jam" ;
    ECHO "notice: will use default configuration" ;
    using python ;
}

# Specify the path to the Boost project.  If you move this project,
# adjust this path to refer to the Boost root directory.
use-project boost
  : /usr/local/boost_1_57_0/ ;

# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the
# boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
# /boost/python.
project
  : requirements <library>/boost/python//boost_python 
                 <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  : usage-requirements <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  ;

# Declare the three extension modules.  You can specify multiple
# source files after the colon separated by spaces.
python-extension timer_ext : timer.cpp ;

# Put the extension and Boost.Python DLL in the current directory, so
# that running script by hand works.
install convenient_copy 
  : timer_ext
  : <install-dependencies>on <install-type>SHARED_LIB <install-type>PYTHON_EXTENSION 
    <location>. 
  ;
```

timer.py

```
import timer_ext
print timer_ext.test()
```

Comment: boost datetime needs boost system, add libraries to requirements.

Comment: Verify that the Boost libraries are in a path available to your system's dynamic linker within the environment in which the Python script is running (e.g., `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `/etc/ld.so.cache`, `/lib`, `/usr/lib`).

Comment: @ForEveR, How do you suggest I do that? I tried to do <linkflags>-lboost_system. And now I have a different error which is ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function(inittimer_ext).

Comment: I ended up not using bjam and just type :
g++ -o timer.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7/ timer.cpp
g++ -o timer_ext.so -shared timer.os -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -lboost_system
This way it all works. As suggested by @ForEveR boostsystem has to be added to the requirements in the Jamroot, which I still don't get how it works